# Torrent files will not download on one Laptop, but download fine on another

Tags: wireless-networking, file-sharing

I have a Laptop and a Netbook.

The Netbook is an Asus, the Laptop is a Sony VPCEH2A4E.

Both of these have been setup by myself (clean install of Windows 7, all drivers properly installed, same configuration etc etc)

Both are on the same LAN, but Torrent files will not download on the Laptop. What is really strange is that I had the Windows 8 release preview on my laptop previously and torrents would not download, and then I wiped the hard drive and put Windows 7 on there and torrents still will not download.

[image: Torrenting]

My netbook downloads torrent files without a problem.

Everything else network related works fine.

I am absolutely stumped. I have run the standard test inside uTorrent, and it has told me that everything is normal. I have ran the Glastnost test to check that my ISP is not throttling and this test has told me that they are not. And my Netbook which has the same version of Windows, and is on the same LAN has no issues.

I am connecting both wirelessly. Why, when two computers are on the same LAN with the same configuration, would Torrent downloads work on one and not on another?

Thanks

Comment: Are you not able to download the .torrent file, or are you having trouble connecting to peers and receiving data?

Comment: Connecting to peers and receiving data

Comment: I know uTorrent says the tests are fine, but have you poked around in your router to look for anything that might be interfering? Is there any port-forwarding going on? Firewall rules? A computer that's set to DMZ?

Comment: Yes I have, uPNP is on, no portforwarding is happening, no firewall rules, nothing in a DMZ

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what torrenting looks like!

Comment: Hmm, that one looks stopped. If you click on it and press play what happens?

Comment: Do other torrent clients present the same problem? Try testing another client to verify if it's a program related issue, or a network/OS related issue.

Comment: You cannot be serious! That worked, but why would an issue like that persist across multiple instances of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push play. ;)

Your netbook probably has auto-start in preferences and you've simply never reformatted that one.

Comment: I think I'm going to quit my job and go work at KFC, thankyou!

Comment: Haha, it happens to everyone. Sometimes it's hard to go back to the VERY basics.